# Illegal ResultSet

Tags: java, mysql, syntax

I got this error:`java.sql.SQLException: Illegal operation on empty result set.`I don't understand why, i loop in eventually searched rows with the while.

```
rs1=st1.executeQuery("select product.price,product.id from product,warehouse,shop
                                where  product.brand ='"
                                + Brand
                                + "' and product.productType='"
                                + Product
                                + "'and shop.quantity + warehouse.quantity='"
                                + Quantity
                                + "' and product.id=shop.idProduct");
                while (rs1.next()) {
                    price = rs.getInt("price");
                    idProduct = rs.getString("id");
                    countWareHouse++;
                }
                if (countWareHouse > 0) {
                    JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(Sale,
                            "Do you want to add this " + Product
                                    + "int the cart?", "CART",
                            JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
                    Prices.add(price);
                }
                }
```

Comment: Can you please show full code ?

Comment: You have not shown us the code which is the culprit. What is there in the `while` loop. And use `PreparedStatement` to build the query.

Comment: `Brand`, `Product`, and `Quantity` should be parameters to avoid sql injection attacks.

Comment: You need to show more code. What you have should not cause this exception.

Comment: in the while i simply increment a count variable.

Comment: Did you copy the actual code? This code shouldn't trigger the exception. One way you could see an exception is if you have a semicolon after your `while (rs1.next()) ; {` or if you are missing a curly brace after `while (rs1.next()) `. Either way, the logic in your code shouldn't throw an exception, so there must be a syntax error of some sort that you are not showing.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight is a syntax Error i forgot to insert rs1.getString instead rs.getString

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within the loop you're using `rs` instead of `rs1`. If this is not issuing a compiler error, I assume `rs` is in the global namespace but empty in the current state.

Comment: recommendation: use literal names on ResultSet instances, not "rs1" etc. Better: productPriceResultSet e.a. in order to prevent.